# How to download file from google-drive by apache camel, I am getting AbstractApiComponent cannot access?

Tags: java, apache-camel, maven-3, dsl

Here I'm trying to download(copy) a file from google-drive
but I'm getting error which is I cannot understand yet. 
I'm not sure about the correct statement for source-route
`from().to(localDrive)`.

```
    public class GdriveCopyFile {
    public static void main(String ar[])throws Exception{

    ArrayList<String> scope = new ArrayList<String>();
    scope.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");

    CamelContext context=new DefaultCamelContext();
    GoogleDriveConfiguration configuration=new GoogleDriveConfiguration();

    configuration.setApplicationName("GdriveCopyFile");
    configuration.setClientId("..");
    configuration.setClientSecret("..");
    configuration.setScopes(scope);

    configuration.setAccessToken("..);
    configuration.setRefreshToken("..");

      GoogleDriveComponent gDriveCompo=new GoogleDriveComponent();
      gDriveCompo.setConfiguration(configuration);      //32
      context.addComponent("google-drive", gDriveCompo); //33

      context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){
      @Override
      public void configure()throws Exception{

      from("google-drive://drive-files/copy?..").to("file:..");

     }
         });
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.stop();
     }}
```

**error:**

> [ERROR] 
>        Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile
>   (default-compile) on project Google-Drive: Compilation
>        failure: Compilation failure:    /home/rajat/workspace/Google-Drive/src/main/java/com/pkgName/gdrive 
>   /Google_Drive/GdriveCopyFile.java:[32,16] error: cannot access 
>   AbstractApiComponent   class file for
>   org.apache.camel.util.component.AbstractApiComponent not
>   found/home/rajat/workspace/Google-Drive/src/main/java/com/pkgName/gdrive/Google_Drive/GdriveCopyFile.java:[33,42]
>   error: incompatible types:         GoogleDriveComponent cannot be
>   converted to Component

And I'm stuck in here what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Maybe you have a classpath problem with mixed version of Camel, or some missing JARs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have `AbstractApiComponent` which is parent class for `GoogleDriveComponent`. Now `org.apache.camel.util.component.AbstractApiComponent` is part of camel core so better look at what version of Camel you're using.

Comment: Yeah it smells like classpath problem with wrong JARs configured there.

Comment: Thank you for considering some changes in camel core I changed version now version is 2.19.3,  after some effort now I'm getting : Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[google-drive://drive-files/copy?fileId=0... because of Missing properties for drive-files/copy, need one or more from [content],  This is my route `from("google-drive://drive-files/copy?fileId=0BxLLYotaad42NmpJRTJNQVpZVDQ")` I tried whatever I knew. Here i must need help. and I appreciating for this.

Comment: For a first, if you're trying to download the file then copy won't do. Read google drive API documentation, EOD camel is just a layer on top of core API functions. `copy` creates a copy of the file, doesn't download it. I haven't used google drive component, but as per doc it does not provide `export` endpoint. Maybe @Claus Ibsen would be able to comment better.